# Second order differential equation question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation

$\dfrac{d^2y}{d^2t}+k\cdot\dfrac{y}{m}=0$

a) let $y(t)= \cos (at)$. Under what conditions on $a$ is $y(t)$ a solution?

b) What initial condition in the yv-plane corresponds to this solution?

c) In term of m and n , what is the period of this solution?

d) sketch the solution curve associate to this point.

I have no idea how to start. I really want to understand this so I wonder if you can explain this problem step by step for me please.

Comment: I'll answer 1, because I don't really know what's the yv-plane (like what's v?) and what's n.

Comment: This equation is called *Harmonic Oscillator*. IMHO it is the most ubiquitous model of all mathematical physics. I guess it is a good idea to read something about it, perhaps on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer most of this question simply by plugging in $y(t)=\cos(at)$ in and comparing terms:

a)

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}[\cos(at)]+\frac{k}{m}\cos(at)=-a^2\cos(at)+\frac{k}{m}\cos(at)=\left(\frac{k}{m}-a^2\right)\cos(at)=0.$$

Since we need the above to hold for all $t$, we require $a^2=\frac{k}{m}$. Thus, either $a=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ or $a=-\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ (does your problem give some interpretation of what $a$ represents that allows you to rule one of these two options out?).

b) I am assuming that by $v$ you mean $\frac{dy}{dt}=-a\sin(at)$. The initial conditions, $y_0$ and $v_0$, are the values of $y$ and $v$ at the initial time (which I assume is $0$). Hence, $y_0=\cos(0)=1$ and $v_0=-a\sin(0)=0$.

c) I am assuming that you mean $k$ instead of $n$. The period is the inverse of the frequency. From before the frequency is $|a|=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, hence the period is $\frac{1}{|a|}=\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$.

d) Just sketch, $y(t)$ (a cosine function of unit amplitude, frequency $\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ and phase sign$(a)\pi$) and $v(t)$ (a sine function of amplitude $\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, frequency $\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ and phase $\pi$).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and explanation.

Comment: Glad it was of any use.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write this equation in the following way:

$y''=-\dfrac{k}{m}y$. and the function $y(t)=\cos(at)$ is a solution if it solves this equation. Let's plug it in:

$ (\cos(at))''=-\dfrac{k}{m}\cos(at) \Leftrightarrow (-a \sin(at))'=-\dfrac{k}{m}\cos(at) \Leftrightarrow a^2\cos(at)=-\dfrac{k}{m}\cos(at) $

Let's note that $\cos(at)$ isn't 0 for all real t, and therefore, we can divide by $\cos(at)$, in order to get that $ a^2=-\dfrac{k}{m} \Rightarrow a=\pm\sqrt{-\dfrac{k}{m}}$.